# Why is it ok to use the view's logical name in PRISM View-based Navigation?

Tags: mvvm, prism

So I'm a complete newbie to PRISM and just trying to get my head around all the concepts, one of which is Navigation.  I have separated all my views into separate modules (along with their vm's) and now I need to be able to switch between them.

Apparently I need to use RegionManager.RequestNavigate and pass in the view's logical name.  I'm just wondering how this is meant to be decoupled as the modules now know about each other (even if just it's just by name).  So if I decide to make a change or use the module in another project it's not going to work anymore.

Unless I've totally misunderstood this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the idea is that while you must have a view name to navigate with, that is all that needs to be known. So if I have 'StockViewer' as a view, I could drop any 'StockViewer' module in, and the other applications would be none the wiser that they are at all different.

For me, I basically created a NameService of sorts, that I can call and have an object representation of names, so I don't fat-finger a name and spend hours trying to troubleshoot why something didn't load.